# Better way to hard-code JSON data as String in Java

Tags: java, json, string, multilinestring, java-text-blocks

I need to keep JSON data in my code for unit-tests as string. For instance,

```json
{
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2
}
```

I know that I can read this data from file or from property, but I need to keep them as string. Currently, I have something like this:

```java
String s = "{\n" +
           "    \"one\": 1,\n" +
           "    \"two\": 2\n" +
           "}";
```

But it looks ugly and in more complex data, it is hard to read and modify it.

I may get rid of `\n` because they are not really needed but for pretty viewing these data later:

```java
String s = "{" +
           "    \"one\": 1," +
           "    \"two\": 2" +
           "}";
```

Also, I may use a trick with quote replacement:

```java
String s = ("{\n" +
            "    'one': 1,\n" +
            "    'two': 2\n" +
            "}").replace('\'','"');
```

Or combine both things at once.

Is there a better way to represent JSON data as a `String` in Java?

For instance, in Python, there are triple quotes:

```py
s = """
{
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2
}
"""
```

Comment: I believe current versions of Java support multiline strings via text blocks via an identical three-quote syntax to that you have presented.

Comment: You could also consider writing your tests in Kotlin, as multi-line strings are available there (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html#string-literals) and you could benefit from other Kotlin features (I find backticks to allow function names to have spaces are nice for tests).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Text Blocks - Java 15+

If you're using Java 15 or late to represent JSON-data instead of string concatenation, which is tedious and error-prone because of the need to escape every quotation mark, you can make use of the [*text blocks*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6).

To create a *text block*, you need to enclose the multiline text in triple double-quote characters `"""`.

```
String myJSON = """ // no characters should appear after the opening delimiter - the text starts from the next line
{
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2
}""";
```

As well as regular strings, *text blocks* support escape sequences, but you don't need to escape quotation marks inside a *text block*.

And note that the opening delimiter `"""` should be *immediately* followed by the *line termination* like in the example shown above.

#### Alternatives

If your project is on a version of Java that doesn't support *text blocks*, but you don't want to dial with string concatenation, you can put your JSON into a *text file* and then read it line by line.

With Java 11 you can read the whole file contents into a string with a single line of code by using [`Files.readString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readString(java.nio.file.Path)):

```
String myJSON = Files.readString(path);
```